# Scale in timeline of ganttProject

Tags: anychart

Ive been wondering if it is possible to set the scale of timeline in a ganttProject graph in Anychart - for example, to be only quarters? I couldn't find it anywhere in the docs.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, but this is can't be done for now. We'r planing to release full Timeline customization options in 7.10.0 version. Please, checkout [roadmap](http://www.anychart.com/products/anygantt/roadmap/) and version [history](http://www.anychart.com/products/anygantt/history/) for more info.

Comment: I can't say I am happy with your answer, but its an answer :)